# Adding static libraries to pod spec file

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, cocoapods, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am trying to create a framework out of the app that is using Google maps now.

This is my FuelMap framework podspec

```
target 'FuelMap' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
end
```

podspec:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

  ...
  s.dependency 'GoogleMaps'
  s.dependency 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'

end
```

Then, I have a regular project which has this pod file

```
target 'Mock' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'FuelMap', :path => './FuelMap'
end
```

Since the regular project is using use_frameworks
I keep running into this error whenever I do pod install

```
The 'Pods-Mock' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries:
```

Is there a work around, so that I can have the library file from GoogleMap Ios statically in the touch framework and then add them as a reference in the pod spec file. So the error would be avoid?

Comment: First remove Google-Maps-ios-utility from pod and try to install. It's work. Have you know the googemaps-ios-utility library? Please check, if need then install.

Comment: A pull request to add static library framework support to CocoaPods is at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/6811

Comment: Thanks @PaulBeusterien is there not a current fix now? I thought of using the subspec and adding the files like so but the pod install from the main project keeps complaining about the transitive error.

Comment: @Beto There is no CocoaPods fix available now. An option is to manually wrap the static libraries into dynamic libraries like what is done by https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS